# How to pass function pointer (callback) and call it without knowing it's type?

Tags: c++, c++11, callback

I have a function pointer as a member to a pure virtual base class. I'd like to pass this pointer to a library which does not know about either of these classes, MyBase or MyClass, and then call the function pointer as a callback into MyClass. I'm writing the lib as well. I want the shared library to call a callback in MyClass.

My question is, how does one pass a function pointer as an argument to a function and have it called without knowing anything about the class itself.

I was considering a pointer to a function pointer, but wasn't sure how to cast properly.

```
class MyBase {
    public:
        virtual void callback() = 0;
        void (MyBase::*callback_ptr)();
};

class MyClass : public MyBase {
    public:
        MyClass();
        void callback() { cout << "callback called" << endl; };
};
```

main.cpp

```
{
    MyClass my_class;
    my_class->callback_ptr = &MyBase::callback;

    lib->set_callback(my_class->callback_ptr);
}
```

lib.cpp

```
class MyLib {
    public:
        // how to declare the member function pointer here?
        void** callback_ptr;

        // how to write sig here?
        set_callback(ptr) { callback_ptr = ptr }

        running() {  
            // how to call the callback here w/o knowing it's type?
        }
}
```

Comment: Use std::invoke. Or write a similar generic function of your own that invokes generic function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
    void myFunction() {
        cout << "Foo::myFunction()\n";
    }
};

void myAPICall(std::function<void()> arg) {
    arg();
}

int main(int, char**) {
    Foo foo;

    // Using a lambda
    myAPICall( [&]() { foo.myFunction(); } );

    // Using bind
    myAPICall( std::bind(&Foo::myFunction, foo) );

    return 0;
}
```

Yields:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 f.cpp -o f && f
Foo::myFunction()
Foo::myFunction()
```

This assumes that you control the API you're calling, and it uses std::function like my code does. If it accepts a C-style function pointer rather than std::function, then you're going to have to play much different games.

Answer (score 2):

To get a function pointer when you don't know the exact type of function that will be called, use `std::function` from the `<functional>` header.

```
class MyLib {
    public:
        // how to declare the member function pointer here?
        std::function<void()> callback_ptr;

        // how to write sig here?
        void set_callback(std::function<void()> ptr) { callback_ptr = ptr; }

        void running() {  
            callback_ptr();
        }
};
```

To use a member function as a `std::function`, use `std::bind`:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass my_class;
    MyLib my_lib;

    my_lib.set_callback(std::bind(&MyClass::callback, &my_class));
    my_lib.running(); // calls my_class.callback()
}
```

Comment: No reason to use `std::bind` (some people wanted it deprecated and later removed from the language, even.) Just use a lambda.